# deep-learning-face:error 'the trns_high is always equal or greater than trns_low'

Tags: matlab, deep-learning

I try to learn this open source code which win the first position in facial expression recognition competition on Kaggle in 2013. The [source code is here .](https://code.google.com/p/deep-learning-faces/)However, when I run the script `script_face_exp.m`,I encounter a problem: ***the trns_high is always equal or greater than trns_low***.

```
{Input} (-1)-->layer{0} Convdata:    nFilters:1 nIJ_grid:48 48, dropout:0.000 
{Hidn}   (0)-->layer{1} ImageMirror: nVisChannels:1 nVisIJ:[48 48],Error using mexcuConvNNoo
Assertion Failed: trns_high not always >= trns_low
```

In addition, I have read the context code about this issue.The `trns_low` and `trns_high` are loaded by GPU. Both the two parameters are from  the 3rd layer named `convxyrs`.

The neural net's configuration is from the file `net_config_basic42.m.` Keeping default setup, `trns_low` is `single([21 21 -pi/4 0.8])`, and `trns_high` is `single([27 27 pi/4 1.2])`.

And then in the file `cu_jitters.h`,line 168 and  line 169, the `trns_low` and `trns_high` are compared one element by one element. If each element of `trns_high` is equal or greater than  the corresponding element in `trns_low`, it will be OK.

OBviously, this condition is met. BUT, this error is always on . I have no idea why.

Why is this error happening?

My environment is AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu 14.04), Cuda 7.0 and Matlab R2013a. GPU is Grid K520.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Error using mexcuConvNNoo
Assertion Failed: trns_high not always >= trns_low

Comment: I guess you mean "the trns_high is **NOT** always equal or greater than trns_low".

Comment: Yes,  you know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

comment line:168 in cuda_ut/modules/conv/cujitters.h

```
//clASSERT(Sum2DInplace(transform_range) == 4, "trns_high not always >= trns_low");
```